# SignalR - Read from serial port in Windows Service

Tags: c#, serial-port, windows-services, signalr, rfid

I need to read data from SerialPort in my Windows service, which use SignalR for communication with RFID reader connected to that serial port. On data read, i want to send data to signalr clients.
I cant find out how to make it work in Service. Also I cant find any working solutions for this problem.

Comment: You have 2 problems, don't confuse your research by trying to look for both explicitly .

Answer (score 2):

As @TheGeneral commented, you have multiple problems to address. You have not provided framework, so I am referencing a lower level at a 4.x.x and SignalR 2.4.1 (not the .NET CORE version although the same principals apply).

1. Create a [Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer).
2. Your Windows service can utilize the [.Net Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client) and be a client.
3. Within your Windows service you can read data coming in on the [serial port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.-ctor?view=netframework-4.5.2).
4. With the read data the service can call method in the HUB.
5. Your HUB can broadcast using Clients.Others to send message to all clients except your service.

You will need to work out the lifetime of the connection, what happens in the service when the connection has failed or is not available, etc.